# Converting Replica to Multi AZ in AWS required downtime?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, multi-az

I have a master - slave set up in amazon AWS.

DB Engine - MySQL.

My master is in Multi AZ but not the read replica.

I want to convert my read replica to multi AZ, does it need any downtime of master or read replica ?

Thanks

Comment: Which DB engine are you using?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - Its MySQL